# How to navigate between html & jsp pages in spring

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

[image: folder structure]I have a Html page called kind.html inside the WEB-INF directory and an other jsp page called registration.jsp inside the WEB-INF folder. I need to put this registration.jsp page inside the WEB-INF directory so it cannot be accessible if a user attempts to get access to it by typing its URL. So my problem is how can i navigate from kind.html to registration.jsp with  link called home I am newbie in this  Thank you.
below is my code snippet and png file

kind.html..............................................

```
<li class='active'><a href='kind.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href="registration.jsp"><span>Register</span></a>


.............................registrationcontroller........................................
@RequestMapping(value="/registration",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String firstRegistration(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        RegistrationModel registrationModel = new RegistrationModel();
        registrationModel.setFirstName(req.getParameter("first_name"));
        System.out.println("controller " + req.getParameter("first_name") );
        registrationModel.setLastName(req.getParameter("last_name"));
        registrationModel.setPassword(req.getParameter("password"));
        registrationModel.setEmailID(req.getParameter("email"));
        System.out.println("controller email " + req.getParameter("email"));
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(req.getParameter("BirthDate"));
            registrationModel.setDOB(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String phoneno=req.getParameter("phoneNo");
        Integer phoneNo = Integer.parseInt(phoneno);
        System.out.println("phone no ...."+phoneNo);
        registrationModel.setPhoneNo(phoneNo);
        registrationModel.setGender(req.getParameter("gender"));
        String age=req.getParameter("Age");
        Long AGE = Long.parseLong(age);
        registrationModel.setAge(AGE);
        registrationModel.setAvtar(req.getParameter("Avtar"));
        System.out.println("avtar"+ req.getParameter("Avtar"));

        Address address = new Address();
        address.setAddressline(req.getParameter("Full-Address"));
        address.setCity(req.getParameter("city"));
        address.setLandmark(req.getParameter("landmark"));
        address.setState(req.getParameter("state"));
        String zipCode =req.getParameter("Zipcode");
        Long zipcode = Long.parseLong(zipCode);
        address.setZipcode(zipcode);
        registrationModel.setAddress(address);

        registrationService.resgistration(registrationModel);

        return "registration.jsp";

    }

..........................registration.jsp.........................................................
<form action="registration" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Register Form</legend>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="BirthDate" placeholder="BirthDate" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="number" name="Age" placeholder="Age" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <select name="gender">
                                    <option value="select">i am..</option>
                                    <option value="m">Male</option>
                                    <option value="f">Female</option>
                                </select><br> <br>

                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="number" name="phoneNo" placeholder="PhoneNo" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="Full-Address"
                                    placeholder="Full-Address" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="landmark" placeholder="landmark" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="city" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="state" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="number" name="Zipcode" placeholder="Zipcode" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="file" name="Avtar" placeholder="Avtar" />
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>![folder structure of project][2]
```

Comment: Clicking on a link whose href is "registration.jsp" is no different from typing the URL of registration.jsp in the address bar. So, since it's under WEB-INF, it's not accessible. And it's a good thing, because a JSP is a view (the V in MVC). All the requests should go to a controller (the C in MVC). So you should NEVER have links to JSPs. Only links to URLs mapped to controllers (in this case, a link to `/registration`).

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet But i want to navigate from kind.html to registration.jsp so how can i do or this is possible

Answer (score 0):

1st to call your pages html is static so you can use mvc resources "" for it, for jsp you have to use ViewResolver for jstl use InternalResourceViewResolver in its configuration as :

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
          <property name="prefix">
              <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
           </property>
          <property name="suffix">
             <value>.jsp</value>
          </property>
</bean>
```

then in your controller use

```
return "registration";
```

also you will need method to handle GET request and change below line

```
<li class='has-sub'><a href="registration"><span>Register</span></a>
```

if you are using Spring boot you will find these configuration automated.

Comment: I had already done this in spring configuration file <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass"
   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
  <property name="suffix" value="" />
 </bean>

Comment: OK so you did not specified suffix to call it as return "registration.jsp"; now you need to add another methods for GET requests too.

Comment: i want to navigate from kind.html to registration.jsp so how can i do

Comment: you will need to add another method with same path but method as GET and it will only return "registration.jsp" and then you will refer to this method as "/registration" in your href so it will be called as get request and it will render jsp by viewer resolver check this video I did before on Spring 3 for jstl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGldP909l6o

Comment: bobo i have done @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody String kindRegistration(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) {
  response.setContentType("text/html");

  return "registration.jsp";

 }<li class='has-sub'><a href="/registration"><span>Register</span></a>

Comment: do not use @ResponseBody as you want viewer resolver to do its work